# Parsing expressions when an operand contain more than one character?

Tags: parsing, expression

I know there are many questions about mathematics expression parsing out there. I have researched and learned the algorithm to convert an infix string to postfix, and use the postfix string to evaluate the value of the expression.

But all of examples I have found deal only with the case that operands of the expression contain only one character. For example "1+2".

**How do you do if the expression is "1 + 123"? The postfix string would become "1123+", so it's unable to be evaluated.**

The method I have thought is to read each character of an operand from the infix string and temporarily keep them in a tempStack. And, when an operator is read, convert the operand in the tempStack to an integer, then push it into the postfix array.

But then the problem follows, my operands would be integer type but my operators are character type. So I can't put them in the same array.

Please suggest me the right way to do this. I know that there are APIs to do this work, but I want to learn this to strengthen my knowledge.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What you are looking for is an [operator-precedence parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser). Or use two stacks, one for operands and one for operators.

Answer (score 0):

You don't transform the input into a 'postfix string' unless you separate the tokens by whitespace. The input "1 + 123" would then become e.g. "1 123 +". But it's better to push the tokens on a stack, for example an array of strings. If the language you use supports algebraic data types, you would create a `Token` type and push onto a stack of `Token`s.